# TensorFlow with mat input by C++

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow

I'm trying to deploy my model trained by TensorFlow in a C++ project with OpenCV.

The problem is: how can I feed a .mat image to the graph without pixel wise assignment which is time consuming I guess. Besides it's also a problem to convert the output tensor to .mat image (actually my model's input and output are both images).

If the pixel wise assignment is unavoidable, how can I accelerate this process?

Comment: Have you tried [OpenCV DNN module](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html)?

Comment: No. You mean I should use the OpenCV DNN module for entire project(loading the tf model and doing prediction) or just use it's data operation? Besides my project has used a library using OpenCV-2.4 which is necessary so that using OpenCV-3.0 seems troublesome.@Miki

Comment: Then all you need is probably in the Blob class. You can have a look at its source code to see how opencv devs handled this problem